# Python/Bokeh: GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, bokeh

I am trying to run the [examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/quickstart.html#using-the-plot-server) in the bokeh/plotting/server folder of the bokeh interactive visualization library and get the error:

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0'
>   failed

I am running UBUNTU 14.04 LTS with the latest Anaconda.

Comment: What is your default browser?

Comment: @asmeurer Sorry for late reply, Firefox v32

Comment: Does changing the default fix it, or manually navigating to `http://localhost:5006/bokeh` after starting the server?

Comment: I'm on Xubuntu 15.04 and I've got those warnings since 13.04. I've learned to ignore them but you can report that to Bugzilla if you want.
Normally everything should works fine even with that, it's just annoying

Answer (score 0):

This question refers to the old first generation Bokeh Server, i.e. the `bokeh-server` command, which has been deprecated and removed for a long time. This issue is not present with the second generation Bokeh server, i.e. `bokeh serve`, which is based on different principles, and is available in all versions of Boken since `0.11.0` and newer.